# Construct a function pertaining to the OEIS sequence A131229 (Numbers congruent to {1,7} mod 10)

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, congruences

OEIS sequence A131229 ("Numbers congruent to {1,7} mod 10") begins $\{1, 7, 11, 17, 21, 27, 31, 37, 41, 47, 51,...\}$.

I want a function $f(x)$, specifically such that $f(\frac{1}{2}) =\frac{7}{2}$, $f(\frac{3}{2}) =\frac{11}{2}$, $f(\frac{5}{2}) =\frac{17}{2}$, $f(\frac{7}{2}) =\frac{21}{2},\ldots$.

The first formula given in the OEIS for A131229 is $a(n) = -3 + sum(5-(-1)^k, k=0..n$).

Answer (score 1):

So you want $$\eqalign{ f\left( 2k + \frac{1}{2} \right) &= \frac{7}{2} + 5k\cr
                       f\left(2k + \frac{3}{2}\right) &= \frac{11}{2} + 5k\cr}$$
Try
$$f(x) = \dfrac{5}{2} x + 2 + \frac{1}{4} \sin(\pi x) $$

Comment: Great! Thanks! Certainly does the trick, and satisfies my purposes. Hadn't thought of employing trigonometric functions in this regard. Are they essential?

Comment: You could add any function $g(x)$ that is $0$ on $\mathbb Z + 1/2$.  There are infinitely many possibilities.